# Populate variable with lastname in a fullname text field in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, text

I have an array of full names,

```
$doctors = @(
    'John Q. Smith',
    'Mary X. Jones',
    'Thomas L. White',
    "Sonia M. O'Toole"
)
```

I would like to pass in to a variable the lastname only from that field. Or maybe only firstinitiallastname.  Here is what I currently have giving me the firstnamelastinitial:

```
try {
    # add firstnames to list
    $firstnames = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    foreach ($doctor in $doctors) {
        $docname = ($doctor -split '\s')
        $docname = $docname[0]+$docname[-1][0]
        $firstnames += $docname
}
```

Again, I would like to see only the last name.  How do I adjust this code for that?

Comment: `$lastName = $docName[-1]`

Comment: Thanks!  I will tinker and see what works.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

EBGreen is on-point...

```
$last_name_only = @()
$first_init_last_name = @()

foreach ($doctor in $doctors) {
    $docname = ($doctor -split '\s')
    $last_name_only += $docname[-1]
    $first_init_last_name += "{0}, {1}" -f $doctor[0], $docname[-1]
}

$last_name_only
$first_init_last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not get all options

```
$Docs = ForEach ($doctor in $doctors) {
    $First,$Middle,$Last = ($doctor -split '\s')
    [PSCustomObject]@{
       Fullname  = $doctor
       Firstname = $First
       Middle    = $Middle
       Lastname  = $Last
       Docname   = $First+$Last[0]
    }
}
$Docs | ft -auto

Fullname         Firstname Middle Lastname Docname
--------         --------- ------ -------- -------
John Q. Smith    John      Q.     Smith    JohnS
Mary X. Jones    Mary      X.     Jones    MaryJ
Thomas L. White  Thomas    L.     White    ThomasW
Sonia M. O'Toole Sonia     M.     O'Toole  SoniaO

$Docs.DocName -join ', '
JohnS, MaryJ, ThomasW, SoniaO
```

**EDIT Or split the names first place with**

```
$doctors = @(
    'John Q. Smith',
    'Mary X. Jones',
    'Thomas L. White',
    "Sonia M. O'Toole"
)| ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header Firstname.MiddleInitial,Lastname
```

Comment: I will tinker and see what works.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-replace` operator, which accepts an array-valued LHS:

```
$lastNames = $doctors -replace '.* (.*)$', '$1'
```

`$1` in the replacement operand refers to what the 1st (and only ) capture group (`(...)`) in the regex operand captured, effectively replacing each input string with the last whitespace-separated token.

<sup>For more on how the `-replace` operator works, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) of mine.</sup>

A complete example:

```
# The input array.
# Note that there's no need to use @(...) to create an array literal.
$doctors =
    'John Q. Smith',
    'Mary X. Jones',
    'Thomas L. White',
    "Sonia M. O'Toole"

# Create a parallel array of last names only.
$lastNames = $doctors -replace '.* (.*)$', '$1'

$lastNames  # output the result
```

The above yields:

```
Smith
Jones
White
O'Toole
```